# jquery UI dialog open is mind-numbingly slow in IE7

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7, modal-dialog, performance

Have a large amount of HTML, but where I thought the bottleneck would be is incorrect: it's when I'm opening the dialog, not when I'm building the string of HTML (~35ms), nor when I'm appending it to the dialog container div (~50ms).  When calling dialog("open") below In FF, I'm consistently getting 1800+ ms, IE7 is around 17000(!) ms.  I can live with 1800ms, but in IE7 (99% of my user base), that's way too long.

```
// prep dialog
$("#print-box").dialog({
    bgiframe: false,
    width:900,
    height: 1000,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    draggable: false
    });

// display selected items in print preview modal
$("#print-preview").click( function() {

    $('#print-box').empty();

    var tmp = ['<div class="print-container">'];
    var rows = $('[name="print-this-listing"]:checked').parents("div.listing").clone();

    for (var i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        tmp.push($(rows[i]).html());
    }

    tmp.push('</div>');

    $('#print-box').html(tmp.join(''));
    $('#print-box').dialog('open');
});
```

Any ideas?  I'm trying to build a print preview page and would rather not take another round trip to the server to fetch all that data again, but it's much much quicker than client-side right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came across a similar problem in using the jQuery UI Dialog. To speed things up try opening the dialog first and then append the data.

```
    $('#print-box').dialog('open');
    $('#print-box').html(tmp.join(''));
```

This seemed to help for me. Also check to see if you have any broken tags or malformed HTML in the string you are appending.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up using an iframe as a "preview window" and hiding elements from the DOM, but went back, and this was indeed noticeably quicker -- still not acceptable for my largish data requirements, but quicker nonetheless.

Comment: I encountered the same issue in IE6 and IE8. My fix was to make an ajax call to get the contents of my dialog, and set it as the contents of the dialog after opening it, as suggested in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although the html() code above does force IE to render the dialog faster in my case it turned out to be the ajax request I was making after the dialog was created that caused the slowness in IE. This particular web application needed to display a wait dialog after a save button was clicked.

Using setTimeout allows the ajax request to occur outside of the dialog rendering. Here's the basic code I used:

```
    function request(requestURL, sendData, asyncRequest) {
        return jQuery.ajax(
        {
            url: requestURL,
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: sendData,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            async: asyncRequest,
            success: function (data, result) {
                if (!result)
                    alert('Failure to retrieve the related lookup data: ' + requestURL);
            }
        }).responseText;
    }

    function modifyProperties(postData) {
        var d;

        // create wait dialog
        jQuery("#wait").dialog({
            maxWidth: 125,
            maxHeight: 75,
            minWidth: 125,
            minHeight: 75,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false
        });

        // ie fix to ensure dialog is rendered prior to ajax request
        setTimeout(function () {
            // make an ajax request after 500ms
            d = request('/mywebservice', postData, false);
            jQuery("#wait").dialog("close");
            var responseObject = JSON.parse(d);
        }, 500);

        return true;
    }

    modifyProperties();
```